# Parsing JSON string which sent as AJAX response from PHP file

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to parse the JSON string sent as ajax response from PHP file using jQuery / JavaScript.

Ajax call:

```
<script>

            $(document).ready(function(){

              var query = $("#editor").html().replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
                      $.ajax({
                           type: "POST",
                           url: "app/query_db.php",
                           data: "q="+query,
                           success: function(resp){    
                                if(resp)    {
                                    alert("Response : "+resp);
                                    $("#res_data").html(resp);

                                }
                                else{
                                    alert("Response: Failed")
                                }
                      });
                    return false;
                });

            });
        </script>
```

PHP file :

```
$db_conn = new db_connect();
    $conn = $db_conn->connectToDB($DBHost,$DBName,$DBUser,$DBPwd);

    $query_res = array();


    if (fill_numeric_array_with_query_assoc($query_res, $sql_query, $conn)) {   // Function to execute the query and fill the result
        //do nothing
    } else {
        echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($conn));  // Error message to display if failed to fetch the data
        exit();
    }
$data = json_encode($query_res);
    echo $data;

Result: [{"uid":"admin","pwd":"xyz"},{"uid":"guest","pwd":"abc"}]
```

Whenever I try to parse the above JSON string I am ending up with 0 and 1 as keys and the other stuff as values. The strange thing is when I copy this result and assign it to a variable in JavaScript it's parsing the string correctly.

Don't know what's going wrong when trying to parse it as AJAX response.

Table format when parsed the JSON string as AJAX response:

[image: Image attached]

Response when assigned to variable in javascript :

```
uid     pwd

admin   xyz

guest   abc
```

Comment: "whenever I try to parse the above json string I am ending up with 0 and 1 as keys and the other stuff as values." Yep that's right, because it's an array with two objects in it. The first object is at index 0 in the array, the second object is at index 1. What were you expecting?

Comment: Your JSON is an array, which have numeric keys, hence the `0` and `1`?

Comment: what you want to try with this object? want to append in table?

Comment: "what you want to try with this object? want to append in table? – Muhammad Akber Khan" - Yeah. I am trying to create a table out of it

Comment: "whenever I try to parse the above json string I am ending up with 0 and 1 as keys and the other stuff as values." Yep that's right, because it's an array with two objects in it. The first object is at index 0 in the array, the second object is at index 1. What were you expecting? – ADyson" - I am trying to create a table by parsing the json string and want the result similar to below                                                                                               Response when assigned to variable in javascript :

uid     pwd

admin   xyz

guest   abc

Comment: ok well you got the first step, you just seemingly didn't do the bit of actually parsing the data and creating some HTML from it. JSON isn't HTML, you can't just append it directly to the DOM and expect it to be formatted nicely. See my answer below for a sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will take the data and turn each object into a row in a table. I'm going to assume that `#res_data` is an empty `<table>` element.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "app/query_db.php",
  data: "q=" + query,
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(resp) {
    if (resp) {
      alert("Response : " + resp);
      $("#res_data").empty();
      if (resp.length > 0) {
        var header = "<tr>";
        for (var key in resp[0]) { 
          "<th>" + key + "</th>"; 
        }
        header += "</tr>";
        $("#res_data").append(header);
        var rows = "";
        for (var i=0; i< resp.length;i++) {
          rows += "<tr><td>" + resp[i].uid + "</td><td>" + resp[i].pwd + "</td></tr>";
        }
        $("#res_data").append(rows);
      }
      else { alert("No data returned"); }
    } else {
      alert("Response: Failed")
    }
  }
});
```

Note the extra ajax option: `dataType: "json"`. This is important. Because your PHP doesn't send any header to tell the client to interpret the response as JSON, it likely interprets it as text. So you have to add `dataType:"json"` so jQuery knows what to do, and makes the response directly into a JS object. Then you should have no problem. If you don't, then it will see it as a string, and then loop through it one character at a time, which will result in the strange output you showed in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However I am looking to create the table header dynamically by extracting the keys from the json string.

Comment: ok well you can loop through the first object in the array and extract the keys. If you're not sure how to do that, I can create an example of that too. You'd use a for...in loop

Comment: Below is the javascript code used for creating the table :               
var col = [];
for (var i = 0; i < resp.length; i++) {
    for (var key in resp[i]) {
  if (col.indexOf(v) === -1) {
      col.push(v);
  }
    }
}
console.log(col);

// CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
var table = document.createElement("table");

Comment: // CREATE HTML TABLE HEADER ROW USING THE EXTRACTED HEADERS ABOVE.

var tr = table.insertRow(-1);                   // TABLE ROW.

for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
    var th = document.createElement("th");      // TABLE HEADER.
    th.innerHTML = col[i];
    tr.appendChild(th);
}

// ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
for (var i = 0; i < resp.length; i++) {

    tr = table.insertRow(-1);

    for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
        var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
        tabCell.innerHTML = resp[i][col[j]];
    }
}

Comment: // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
var divContainer = document.getElementById("res_data");
divContainer.innerHTML = "";
divContainer.appendChild(table);

Comment: it's working fine when I declare the var resp = [
            {"uid":"admin","pwd":"xyz"},{"uid":"guest","pwd":"abc"}
        ]

Comment: did you change to `dataType: "json"` as per my sample? And why didn't you put that code in your original question? It looked like you didn't actually know how to create the HTML.

Comment: actually that code of yours has an error - the variable "v" is not defined. If you change `v` to `key` inside the `for (var key in resp[i])` loop it works fine and prints the table. The only reason it wouldn't do that is if `resp` is not defined properly. Since your PHP doesn't send any header to tell the client to interpret the response as JSON, it likely interprets it as text. So you have to add `dataType:"json"` so jQuery knows what to do, and makes the response directly into a JS object. Then you should have no problem other than that `v` bug.

Comment: I've also updated the answer to create the header dynamically, albeit a slightly different way than you did.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My bad "v" should be key I missed type it. will give it a try with datatype:json

Comment: Thanks a lot Adyson adding dataType in ajax call worked like a charm